# Are Golems “Humanoid” for UA Ranger?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, class-feature, ranger, unearthed-arcana

Our game 5e game includes a ranger  using the Unearthed Arcana rules. The ranger has chosen Humanoids for their favored enemy, and we are trying to determine if a Forest Golem (or any other Golem) counts as “humanoid” for the purposes of the favored enemy damage bonus. Golems are typically described as “generally humanoid” but do not appear in the Monster Manual list of humanoids, I assume, because they are constructs. Any insight is appreciated, as we anticipate folding this Forest Golem NPC into our campaign as a regularly appearing character.

Comment: Which "UA Ranger" do you mean? I'm guessing you mean [UA: The Ranger, Revised](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/UA_RevisedRanger.pdf) from 2016?

Comment: Also: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 17):

### Golems are not humanoid

Page 6 of the *Monster Manual* introduces the concept of [creature type](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#Type):

> A monster's type speaks to its fundamental nature. Certain spells, magic items, class features, and other effects in the game interact in special ways with creatures of a particular type. For example, an *arrow of dragon slaying* deals extra damage not only to dragons but also other creatures of the dragon type, such as dragon turtles and wyverns.

Every creature belongs to one (or occasionally two) of the fourteen types: aberrations, beasts, celestials, constructs, dragons, elementals, fey, fiends, giants, humanoids, monstrosities, oozes, plants, and undead.

There are many game mechanics that interact with creature type: spells, weapons, abilities and more. In this case, the Ranger class has a Favored Enemy feature whose bonus damage is limited to targets of a specific creature type (or if you pick humanoid, is limited to two sub-groups within that type).

Looking at the entries for the various [Golems](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/monsters-g#Golems) in the *Monster Manual*, it is clear that Golems always belong to the type *construct*, never *humanoid*. This is the case in all official published versions of golems. Looking further at the *Monster Manual*, I can see three places where Golems are compared to humans or humanoids.

[Clay Golem](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/clay-golem) (MM, 168):

> Sculpted from clay, this bulky golem stands head and shoulders taller
> than most human-sized creatures. It is human shaped, but its
> proportions are off.

[Flesh Golem](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/flesh-golem) (MM, 169):

> A flesh golem is a grisly assortment of humanoid body parts stitched
> and bolted together into a muscled brute imbued with formidable
> strength.

[Stone Golem](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/stone-golem) (MM, 170):

> Though most bear humanoid features, stone golems can be carved in any
> form the sculptor can imagine.

But these are descriptions to give you the narrative flavour, so that you and your players can better imagine these relentless creatures. At the top of each stat block, it is clear that while they may have two arms, two legs and a head and walk upright, mechanically, they are clearly *constructs*.

On a side note, when a player picks a Ranger's Favored Enemy, if they select *humanoids*, this is limited to two races/lineages of humanoids (e.g. elf, halfling, orc, dwarf, etc.) and does not apply generally to all humanoids.

Comment: Regarding your mention of the Favored Enemy feature requiring you to pick 2 specific kinds of humanoid: I'm guessing the querent is using the [UA revised ranger](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/UA_RevisedRanger.pdf) from 2016, which can indeed pick "humanoid" as a favored enemy in general, rather than having to pick 2 specific kinds of humanoid.

Answer (score 8):

### It's all about Creature Tags

"Humanoid" is a creature type, like "Undead" or "Fey". So a creature only counts as humanoid (mechanically speaking) if its stat block declares it as a humanoid creature. Don't look into fluff texts of creature descriptions. All that counts are the creature's type/tags, when it comes to whether that creature is affected by a particular effect or not.

Answer (score 7):

#### Golems are constructs, not humanoids.

The Favored Enemy feature refers to the creature’s type:

> Choose a type of favored enemy:  aberrations, beasts, celestials, constructs, dragons, elementals, fey, fiends, giants, monstrosities, oozes, plants, or undead. Alternatively, you can select two races of humanoid (such as gnolls and orcs) as favored enemies.

Since all golems are constructs, not humanoids, a ranger that has chosen humanoid does not get a bonus against golems.

Comment: It may also help to cover that humanoid is both a form of creature and type of creature, but it's type that matters here.